# Eigenspaces and Eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I am revising for a Linear Algebra exam by going through some previous quiz questions, that I have True/False answers to, but not the reasoning or counterexamples.

I am stuck on the following:

> Suppose $T\in \mathcal{L}\left(\mathbb{F}^5\right)$ and $\dim E(4,T)=4$. Then either $T-2I$ or $T+2I$ is invertible.

**Edit:** The notation is from Axler, Linear Algebra Done Right 3e. I guess it's hard to know when an author is using non-standard notation when you're new to a subject.

$\mathbb{F}$ is some field, either the reals or the complex numbers.

$\mathcal{L}$ refers to the set of linear operators over some vector space, in this case $\mathbb{F}^5$.

$E(4,T)$ refers to the eigenspace with respect to eigenvalue $4$ for linear operator $T$.

$I$ is the relevant identity matrix, in this case, the $5\times 5$ identity matrix.

$T-2I$ refers to the matrix of linear operator $T$ with respect to some basis, which is a $5\times 5$ matrix, minus the scalar product of $-2$ and a $5\times 5$ identity matrix.

Comment: Can you explain your notation to make it easier to understand and answer your questions?

Comment: In particular, we don't know what you mean by $F$, by $L$, by $E$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $T-2I$ is not invertible, then $2$ is also an eigenvalue and it will have $1$ eigenvector which $4$ is an eigenvalue with $4$ indepdnent eigenvectors. Hence $T+2I$ must be invertible as $-2$ cannot be another eigenvalue.

However, note that there are cases where both $T-2I$ and $T+2I$ are invertible.

For example, let $$T(x)=diag(4,4,4,4,1)x$$

then both $T-2I$ and $T+2I$ are both invertible.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose neither $T-2I$ nor $T+2I$ were invertible, the we would have for $T$:

- an eigenspace of dimension $4$ for the eigenvalue $4$,
- an eigenspace of dimension at least $1$ for the eigenvalue $2$, and
- an eigenspace of dimension at least $1$ for the eigenvalue $-2$.

Since the sum of eigenspaces for distinct eigenvalues is always a direct sum
(and $4,2,-2$ are distinct values since $F$ is not of characteristic $2~$or$~3$), the sum of the three mentioned subspaces would be a subspace of dimension at least $6$, but $F^5$ does not have any such subspaces. Hence our assumption is impossible.